# playframework2 redirect defined only in routes file

Tags: redirect, routes, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

How can I define a redirect by changing only the conf/routes files?

I have the following route

```
GET     /a     controllers.Application.a(countryCode,nodeName)
```

I would like just to change it to something like

```
GET     /a     controllers.Application.a(countryCode,nodeName)
GET     /b     /a
GET     /a/    /a
```

This will mean that whenever i receive /b or /a/ with some parameters i will just redirect to /a that will process it in the same time with changing the url in the client browser.

A second more complicated routing would be for

```
GET     /a/:countryCode/node/:nodeName     controllers.Application.a(countryCode,nodeName)
```

I would like just to change it to something like

```
GET     /a/:countryCode/node/:nodeName     controllers.Application.a(countryCode,nodeName)
GET     /b     /a
GET     /a/    /a
```

Answer (score 3):

`GET  /b controllers.Default.redirect(to = "/a")`

Shameless plug:
If you want to redirect all routes from `/a/` to `/a` without going insane, check out my project [play-trailing-slash](https://github.com/mariussoutier/play-trailing-slash).

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't realized that my case is a little more complex. I also have parameters in the route. I will rephrase my question to include this case. Nevertheless your answer is good for the simple case.